# How to close an ssh tunnel in python

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I am writing a Python application that accesses a remote Mysql database using ssh tunneling.
I setup the tunnel with

```
os.system("ssh -fNg -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@host")
```

and everything works perfectly. The problem is:

what is the python code to close the ssh tunnel?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `os.system("exit")`?

Comment: you could try paramiko together with this: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py .

Comment: os.system("exit") is what I was looking for, thanks. I will have a look at Paramiko too.

Comment: Its not so easy since you forked the tunnel into the background.  A discussion on how to deal with this in scripts is at https://gist.github.com/scy/6781836.  A sysadmin approach would be to determine how to recognize the tunnel process in ps output from which its PID can be determined and used to kill it.

Comment: Try [sshtunnel](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel#example-3)

Answer (score 3):

### os.system('exit') doesn't work

The process that creates the tunnel still runs in the background

```
>>> command = 'ssh -fNg vagrant@localhost -p2222 -L 8000:localhost:8000'
>>> os.system(command)
>>> os.system('exit')

ps -A | grep ssh
7144 ??         0:00.04 ssh -fNg vagrant@localhost -p2222 -L 8000:localhost:8000
```

This shows the process is still running and the tunnel is still working, and `os.system` doesn't return the process ID so we can use it to terminate the process (it returns the exit code)

### Use subprocess to return a handle to the process

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
proc.terminate() # this terminates the process
```

Answer (score 0):

- Its correct sys.exit() won't exist the script and keeps the tunnel open.
- Here is how I close an SSH tunnel using Python and in turn allows me to terminate the
  Python script.
- In my close function I pass the tunnel connection I created:

`def close(self, tunnel = None):    
        if tunnel is not None:
        # close tunnel connection.
            tunnel.close()`

- I created the SSH connection using Paramiko as

`def connect(params):
    # Create an SSH tunnel
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (params['ssh_ip_address'], int(params['ssh_port'])),
        ssh_username=params['ssh_username'],
        ssh_private_key=params['ssh_key'],
        ssh_private_key_password=params['ssh_key_file_password'],
        remote_bind_address=('localhost', int(params['ssh_remote_forward_port'])),
        local_bind_address=('localhost',int(params['ssh_local_forward_port']))  
    tunnel.start()
return tunnel`